# How to delete items on the listview in Fragments?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to delete the items from the fragments. When long click on the items than a action bar is changed and a delete button appears. I click on the delete button The item seems to be deleted from the list view. But when I restart the app the item appears again.

```
public class ReadFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView spinner;
    TextView empty;
    String selected;
    List<String> list;
    String[] filenames;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read, container,
                false);
        spinner = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        this.spinner.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));
        getFilenames();

    getactionbar();

        return rootView;

    }

    private void getFilenames() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        filenames = getActivity().fileList();
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
            // Log.d("Filename", filenames[i]);
            list.add(filenames[i]);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> filenameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1, list);

        spinner.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                selected = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReadData.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", selected);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
    private void getactionbar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinner.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        spinner.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                                  long id, boolean checked) {
                // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
                // such as update the title in the CAB
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.ic_action_discard:

                        deletefiles();


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            private void deletefiles() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = spinner.getCheckedItemPositions();
                 int itemCount = spinner.getCount();

                 for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                     if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                         filenameAdapter.remove(list.get(i));
                     }
                 }
                 checkedItemPositions.clear();
                filenameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }   


            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu for the CAB
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
                // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
                // an invalidate() request
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me deleting the item forever, I mean once it is deleted it should not appear in the listview again when the app is relaunched.

Comment: Where do you load your content from? If the objects are reappearing are you sure youre not reloading that list from an external source (e.g. SQLite, web service, etc).

Comment: I have the data saved in the internal storage. So the items in the listview is the names of the files in the internal storage. I want to delete the files in the internal storage which is shown through Listview.

Comment: If you're loading the list from data store on a file in resources I do not think you can delete or modify that file once the apk is built. What I would do is simply note which value has been deleted and not load deleted values into the list onCreate/onResume

Comment: I am not loading the data from resource but I have a class from where I save the data. and the name of the data is then showed in the listview.

Comment: So you save it to a file you create on external storage? Can you show the code where you create/write/read that file.

Answer (score 1):

Try, tries it worked here

```
final Button btnRemove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            lst.remove(adapter.getItem(2));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });;
```

Comment: according to my code than it should be. filenameAdapter.remove(filenameAdapter.getItem(i)); notifyDataSetChanged(); But it doesnot work

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); <--- This line says The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener(){}

Comment: have the project on github? so I can simulate faster

Comment: No sorry I donot have. But thank you for your help. But if it helps you, I have the data saved in the internal storage. So the items in the listview are the names of the files in the internal storage. I want to delete the files in the internal storage. When I delete the Listview items, it should also delete the data in the internal storage.

Comment: link that worked ... just testing github

https://github.com/marcostomazini/AndroidRemoveItemListViewClick

Comment: Thanks for the codes. My question is all the items are the files saved on the internal storage. So when I delete the files like you said, would I be deleating the files from the internal storage also or only on the list?

Comment: Here is the Github page if you still want to see the code and help me. https://github.com/Lifestohack/Password-Protect-V2.0/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is intentionally, but you copy the items from the Activity into another array before passing it to the Adapter. So when you call adapter.remove() it only removes the item from the new one leaving the original List in the Activity untuched (guess you save that one to storage in the Activitys onPause or something).

Comment: Ok, I'm a little bit lost here. The Activity.fileList() returns a String array, what you copy into an array list. Deleting from that List has no effect on the original array, not to mention the file system, so when you restart your app it will be the same as the previous startup. Why do you expect different, am I missing something?

Comment: No you are not missing anything. I am the one who is missing many things. I wanted to delete the file from the internal storage, which I find really difficult to do. I have a class from where I show the saved data. In that class I am able to implement the delete button but when I go back to the list, it is not refreshed. I have to restart the app.  So that is why I wanted to delete the files from the list view because in fragments I was able to refresh the listView but I cannot really delete the stored data. And yes as you understood it only deletes the list item until the app restarts.

Comment: I see. So the right way to do this would be to delete the file in the loop in the deletefiles() function. I think you can do it with deleteFile(String name);
Also in my opinion it is a more clean way if the adapter actually displays the files, so I would only delete the file and reload the file list. Multiple representations just can be a mess sometimes.
Also please accept the answer if it is satisfactory :)

Comment: I already tired to delete with deleFile(String name), it did not work in Fragment. I used in Activity, it works but not in Fragment. I am working with Fragment and it doesnot work.

Comment: Try with getActivity().deleteFile(String) then.